# docker-compose does not update resolv.conf

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have the following simplified docker-compose file:

```
version: '2'
services:
    test.base:
        container_name: test.base
        image: docker.pnet.ch/r-base:latest
        restart: on-failure
        networks:
            - mynet
        dns: 192.168.198.2
        dns_search:
            - pext.ch
            - pnet.ch
networks:
    mynet:
        driver: bridge
        driver_opts:
            com.docker.network.enable_ipv4: "true"
        ipam:
            driver: default
            config:
                - subnet: 192.168.198.0/24
                  gateway: 192.168.198.1
```

With this I expect to have the following entries in the containers /etc/resolv.conf:

```
search pext.ch pnet.ch
nameserver 192.168.198.2
```

But instead I have the following:

```
search pext.ch pnet.ch
nameserver 127.0.0.11
options ndots:0
```

When I manually start the container using docker run with --dns 192.168.199.2 /etc/resolv.conf contains a nameserver with the given ip address.

Is there anything wrong with my docker-compose file or is it a bug in docker-compose?

I'm using docker version 1.10.3 on RHEL and docker-compose 1.9.0

Answer (score 12):

I used `volumes:` to work around this problem. In your case:

```
version: '2'
services:
    test.base:
        container_name: test.base
        image: docker.pnet.ch/r-base:latest
        restart: on-failure
        networks:
            - mynet
        volumes:
            - ./resolv.conf:/etc/resolv.conf
```

Where the `./resolv.conf` file contains what exactly you expected as:

```
search pext.ch pnet.ch
nameserver 192.168.198.2
```

Here assumes the `resolv.conf` file is on the same folder as your docker-compose file.

Comment: I ended up doing the same. I couldn't make my container resolve properly by specifying dns in docker-compose.yml :(

Comment: In the event that you are referring to other containers in your docker-network by a container name and you set your volume as set in your answer, you lose the needed entry (e.g. 127.0.0.11) to resolve the names appropriately. I'm still trying to get this to work cleanly.

Answer (score 9):

Networking in Docker Compose file format v2 it's [different from version 1](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/4177), and I think that's the actual problem. It's also confusing that a `docker run ...` command works while the `docker-compose ...` don't. I experienced the same issue.

What I found is that Docker Compose v2 creates a **user-defined network** for the containers defined in the `docker-compose.yml` file, whereas `docker run ...` by default uses the **bridged network**, named `docker0` on the host. Also, with custom networks docker uses an [embedded DNS server](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/configure-dns/) (that's the `127.0.0.11`). The docs say:

> The IP addresses passed via the `--dns` option is used by the embedded DNS server to forward the DNS query if embedded DNS server is unable to resolve a name resolution request from the containers. These `--dns` IP addresses are managed by the embedded DNS server and **will not be updated in the container's `/etc/resolv.conf` file**.

I think the last line answers your question. Anyway, your container should be resolving correctly, doesn't it?

Comment: I have the same issue. Although /etc/resolv.conf not being modified is expected as you point out, my container would not resolve properly unless I modified resolv.conf, as pointed out in other answer.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed earlier `resolv.conf` does not change for quite certain reasons, so I found dirty hack for `docker-compose`: changing `resolv.conf` inplace during `docker build`.

You should make file changes in the beginning of your command and it remain unchanged until it end.

Like this:

`RUN echo "nameserver 10.100.1.13" > /etc/resolv.conf  && apt update`

I know this is far from good coding practices, but I  think it's more elegant, than mounting `/etc/resolf.conf` from outer world.

Answer (score 0):

I was running the ubuntu version of docker holded in this respository (docker.io 18.06.0). I removed that version an install docker.io using apt-get install docker.io. So now I have this version:

```
Client:
Version:    17.12.1-ce
API version:    1.35
Go version: go1.10.1
Git commit: 7390fc6
Built:  Wed Apr 18 01:23:11 2018
OS/Arch:    linux/amd64

Server:
Engine:
Version:    17.12.1-ce
API version:    1.35 (minimum version 1.12)
Go version: go1.10.1
Git commit: 7390fc6
Built:  Wed Feb 28 17:46:05 2018
OS/Arch:    linux/amd64
Experimental:   false
```

Containers running with docker-compose don't have the file `resolv.conf` with the dns configured as expected, but each container can access the Internet. I think that change solve my problem.